# How can I filter rows of a model by a certain value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to return just the elements that belong to a user. The `user_id` value is a column from Run. What I want is to select just the `runs` that are from the `current_user`.

```
def index
  @runs = Run.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @runs }
  end
end
```

As tried something like

```
@runs = Run.where(user_id= => current_user.id)
```

But it didn't worked. How should I do it?

Comment: I've added the [tag:activerecord] tag under the assumption that `Run` is an ActiveRecord model; if is something else—for example, if you are using a different ORM such as Sequel—then please indicate that in your question.

Comment: Your edited code has invalid syntax. That should be: `@runs = Run.where(:user_id => current_user.id)` or `@runs = Run.where( user_id:current_user.id )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an association between your User model and your Run model you should be able to do simply `current_user.runs`. For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :runs
end

class Run < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

*I don't know your actual DB schema or model names, though, so I can't be sure if this is correct for your situation.*

Answer (score 2):

A parameterized `.where()` uses a syntax like:

```
@runs = Run.where("user_id = ?", current_user.id)
```

It can also be done as a hash, which may be a little more readable:

```
@runs = Run.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
```

### Don't do it this way (as a plain string)...

as it potentially opens up SQL injection vulnerabilities, even though the `id` is unlikely to be tampered with...

```
# Don't do this...
@runs = Run.where("user_id = #{current_user.id}")
```

Review the [documentation on ActiveRecord conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions) for full details.

Comment: However `user_id` is a column of `Run`. I want to filter the runs where their `user_id` are the same as the `current_user.id`. If I do as you said I get a `no such column` error.

Comment: @JoãoDaniel Then you had better be very clear about what columns are present in the `Run` model.

Comment: @JoãoDaniel The query this should generate is `SELECT * FROM runs WHERE user_id = <current_user.id>` Using the `.where()` will search against columns of `Run`.

Answer (score 1):

Gem [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) is great for these purposes. If you add `user_id` condition for `Run` in `Ability` class with `:read` param, and `load_resource` in controller, gem automaticall load only needed runs for current user in `index` action. Read docs for addition :)